# Test Class Showing an error

Tags: unit-test, webservices

When i implemented the test class for webservice it showing an error is

**Compile Error: Invalid type: AccountWrapper.Contacts**  **in my test class**

My Class

```
  webservice String accName;
  webservice  contacts;  
 }
// CONTACT  FIELDS
 global class {
   webservice String clName;
   webservice String cfName;
 }
 global class OutputClass
 {
  webservice String resName;     
 }  
 webservice static  insert(InputClass req){


    acc = new account();
   acc.name = wrapper.accName;
   System.debug('check:'+acc);
    accList.add(acc);

        con1 = new Contact();
     con1.LastName = clName;
        con1.FirstName =cfName;          
        contactList.add(con1);  
      }
      try
      {  
        Database.upsert(contactList);
      }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
      Database.rollback(sp);
      res.errorMessage = 'ERROR_CREATING_Contact: ' + e.getMessage();
      return res;
     }   

   } // End of If Condition
   } // End of For Loop

       // Return statement       

       return res;          

} // End Method
```

} // End Class

And My Test Class IS

```
   @isTest
 private class Test12 {
public  static testMethod void UnitTest() {


     accWrapper.accName = 'Stest';
    accWrapper.accNumber = '12389';
    req.accounts.add(accWrapper);


     coWrapper.clName = 'TestlName';
     coWrapper.cfName = 'TestfName';
     coWrapper.email = 'das@yahoo.com';
     coWrapper.mobile = '1423456542';
     req.contacts.add(coWrapper); 

     Sample.input(req);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you understand the error message ?

Comment: @samuel NO i can't getting exactly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ususally error messages tell you the problem:

> Compile Error: Invalid type: AccountWrapper.Contacts in my test class

Somewhere you are trying to define a variable as of the type of `AccountWrapper.Contacts`, while that is not a type. Types are apex object definitions(=blueprints), either defined by an sObject or an apex class definition.

Looking at your AccountWrapper Class:

```
global class AccountWrapper{    
  webservice String accName;
  webservice List<ContactWrapper> contacts;  
 }
```

Your class has 2 fields, accName of the `String` Type, and contacts of the `List<ContactWrapper>` type.

Looking at your non compiling test code:

```
    MainClass89.RequestClass req = new MainClass89.RequestClass();
    req.accounts = new List<MainClass89.AccountWrapper>();
     accWrapper.accName = 'Stest';
    accWrapper.accNumber = '12389';
    req.accounts.add(accWrapper);

     MainClass89.ContactWrapper coWrapper = new MainClass89.ContactWrapper();
     **req.contacts = new List<AccountWrapper.Contacts>();** // **Error Occur Point**
```

**You're trying to populate the req.contacts field with a list of the fieldname, not the contactwrapper type.** You should use the type as declared in the definition of your class, this is `List<ContactWrapper>`.

Additionally, your code is trying to assign the contacts field on the inputRequest object rather than the accountwrapper object.

Comment: where i have to change the code..in my test class

Comment: I am not going to post that. It is explained in my answer, I want you to understand what i've posted, or ask me what you do not understand.

Comment: MainClass89.ContactWrapper coWrapper = new MainClass89.ContactWrapper();
     **req.contacts = new List<AccountWrapper.Contacts>();**

Comment: i called the contacts with contact wrapper only.

Comment: I understand that. Can you explain me what TYPE of field "req.contacts" is ? You must know what type it is, if you want to put a value in it. The value type should be the same as the type of the field.

Comment: Can you modify me where i have done mistake for contacts  Sample.ContactWrapper coWrapper = new Sample.ContactWrapper();
     **req.contacts = new List<AccountWrapper.Contacts>();** // **Error Occur Point**
     coWrapper.clName = 'TestlName';
     coWrapper.cfName = 'TestfName';
     coWrapper.email = 'das@yahoo.com';
     coWrapper.mobile = '1423456542';
     req.contacts.add(coWrapper); 

     Sample.input(req);
}

Comment: Can you explain me what TYPE of field "req.contacts" is ? If you can, you will see your mistake and be able to fix it yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13494/discussion-between-sathya-and-samuel-de-rycke)